# Prevent remote users opening database via VPN

Tags: vba, ms-access, vpn

I have a client with an ms-access 2016 database split into a front end (each user with their own copy on their machine) and a back end (on the server).  Remote workers can successfully use the database with RDS.  However, some users are attempting to work over VPN and this has caused corruption of their front end database.

Using VBA is there any way when the front-end opens, I can determine if the user has come via VPN and then give them a message and automatically shut down the front-end database?

Never had to solve this one before and online searches have not given me anything useful so far.  So if anyone has a solution for this that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are taking wrong approach here.   This should be done on a network level.  The back-end access db should not be accessible on the network and the front end should just check if the e.g. mapped network drive is accessible.

An example:

```
Sub Testing_Mapped_Drive()
  If (Len(Dir("M:\"))) Then
     MsgBox "Mapped drive connected."
  Else
     MsgBox "Mapped drive not available!"
  End If
End Sub
```